# How to manage the scope of db context in .NET Core when SaveChanges() fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a .NET Core console app that is triggered by an Azure service bus queue. My understanding is that the default lifetime of the DbContext via DI is `Scoped` and that it's recommended to let DI and the framework manage the lifetime instead of using `using` statements. However, we have the following case where we call `SaveChanges()`, it fails, so we try to call it again to write a log to the db. What's the recommended approach here? It feels weird to use `using` when the context is injected by DI to the calling class.

```
try
{
    db.Add(new MyEntity());
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex) // a constraint is violated
{
    db.Add(new LogEntity("Unable to save MyEntity"));
    db.SaveChanges(); // this fails because MyEntity is still in scope of the context
}
```

Comment: You are correct - you should not `Dispose` of `db` (i.e. no need for `using`) if it was been injected in. That is the container's job. I humbly disagree with the below answer (in terms of `using`). In terms of logging, I'd suggest writing to the log using a logging library, rather than using the db context.

Comment: maybe you can set the entity state as detached and then save the log, if it is possible? like db.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Detached

Comment: It is recommended to split Business logic and Log logic with different `DbContext`. I recommend you inject two DbContext for different options. Or, you may consider creating a new service for logging which will inject `DbContext` into it. Then, use this log service while required.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that the default lifetime of the DbContext via DI
>   is Scoped and that it's recommended to let DI and the framework manage
>   the lifetime instead of using `using` statements.

This is not accurate, DI is a method for instantiating objects, but you can still control the scope of the objects... example using Ninject ([more info](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)):

```
// this would create a new MyType instance on every request
kernel.Bind<IMyType>().To<MyType>().InTransientScope();

// this would share MyType instance within the same Thread
kernel.Bind<IMyType>().To<MyType>().InThreadScope();

// this would share MyType instance within the same Web Request
kernel.Bind<IMyType>().To<MyType>().InRequestScope();
```

---

Regarding the scope of DbContext, see [Microsoft's recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#0cb87d0d-0981-48f1-ab1a-6fc0fdfa5e9f_c):

> A DataContext is lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical
>   LINQ to SQL application creates DataContext instances at method scope
>   or as a member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of
>   related database operations.

So it is generally a good idea to share the same instance of `DbContext` within the same method... **the exception here is with logging**. It is not a good idea to mix your Logger's `DbContext` with the operations that it is logging. Logging should be independent of these operations... you many choose to log your message in a text file, email, DB... if you want to use DB for logging, you can consider using a different DB for your log message. Also Consider using logging frameworks such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/), etc

Comment: Your link is regarding `Linq.DataContext`, not `DbContext`. Regardless, thanks for the input. We are considering setting the DbContext lifetime to Transient or finding a way to separate our logging service.

Answer (score 0):

```
//// one of safest way as DbContext is not thread safe 
List<Model> Items;
await using (var _dataContext = new DataContext(connectionString:"connection String"))
{
    Boughts = await _dataContext.YourModel.ToListAsync();
}
```